# Are there military arguments why Ukraine would blow up the Kakhovka dam?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine

Today the Dniepro river dam at Kakhovka [was breached](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-65818705). It is not obvious which side is responsible. While the Ukrainina side blames the Russians, the Russian side, obviously, blames the Ukrainians. So far the arguments I have heard for the Russian position are

- a comment that Ukraine had shelled the area at the dam before,
- allegation that Ukraine wants to harm the Russian-held Crimea, as part of it is supplied with water from the reservoir.

What other possible reasons are there, and what have commentators and politicians on the Russian side told so far about the alleged reasons of Ukraine blowing up the dam?

---

*The reason I am asking this question is a very personal deficit. I am able to read media in English and German, but not in Russian. In order to build an opinion, I'd like to understand and compare the arguments of both sides. But what I find so far is that the media I read take a lot of time to cite pro-Ukrainian positions, while the Russian arguments seem to show up in quite short sentences.*

*This lead me to ask you if there were arguments offered that were missing in my personal selection of media, or that did not appear to me while thinking about it. There **is** a one-sidedness to my question in that I feel I have heard sufficiently from one side, but not the other.*

*But please, do not take this as promoting a certain view of events. Evaluating the arguments should not be done here.*

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146534/discussion-on-question-by-ccprog-are-there-military-arguments-why-ukraine-would); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Question about Ukraine is on topic, identical question about Russia off topic, amazing. I think now both should be closed.

Comment: @Stančikas [Russia is open again, for now](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/79860/21531).  .  Yo yo continues ;-).  But yes, either both up or both down, mods should close the odd one if needed

Comment: Note, FWIW, that dams have [special protections under international laws](https://lieber.westpoint.edu/attacking-dams-part-ii-1977-additional-protocols/) - not sure about RU/UA's signatory status on this though.

Comment: Can we resurrect one of convert's deleted answers?  The latest is pretty solid and whatever was wrong with its first iteration or the delete/report cycling doesn't seem to warrant perma-nuking a serviceable attempt at answering.

Comment: I'd like to point out that **the bounty is not offered by me, the question author**.

Answer (score 11):

According to the official Russian government sources, the military arguments why Ukraine blew up the Kakhovka dam are as follows:

1. It serves to deprive Crimea of water.
2. It serves to relocate Ukrainian troops to the attack positions away from the Kherson region.
3. It is connected to the unsuccessful Ukrainian counteroffensive.

Making sense of these goals, especially of goals 2 and 3 *together*, is left as an exercise to the reader.

**References:**

> Одна из целей подрыва киевским режимом Каховской ГЭС связана с тем, чтобы лишить Крым воды, заявил пресс-секретарь президента России Дмитрий Песков.
> Министр обороны России Сергей Шойгу заявил, что Киевский режим подорвал Каховскую ГЭС, чтобы перебросить войска в район своих наступательных действий с херсонского направления, ослабив там свои позиции. По словам министра, Киев совершил теракт, подорвав Каховскую ГЭС, это привело к затоплению значительных территорий.

*[МИД России назвал подрыв Каховской ГЭС террористическим актом - РИА Новости, 06.06.2023](https://ria.ru/20230606/terakt-1876576840.html)*

> One of the goals of blowing up by the Kyiv regime by the Kakhovka hydroelectric power plant is connected to depriving Crimea of water, said Dmitry Peskov, Press Secretary of the President of Russia.
> Minister of Defence of Russia Sergei Shoigu said that the Kyiv regime blew up the Kakhovka hydroelectric power plant in order to relocate the troops into the region of its attack from the Kherson direction, weakening its positions there. According to the Minister, Kyiv carried out the terrorist act by having blown up the Kakhovka hydroelectric power plant, and this caused flooding of substantial territories.

*[MoD of Russia called the breach of the Kakhovka hydroelectric power plant a terrorist act - RIA News, 06.06.2023](https://ria.ru/20230606/terakt-1876576840.html)*

---

> Песков заявил, что диверсию на Каховской ГЭС совершила Украина. По его словам, она связана с неудачным контрнаступлением Киева. [...]
> Министр обороны РФ Сергей Шойгу отметил, что цель подрыва Киевом Каховской ГЭС заключается в переброске подразделений ВСУ с херсонского направления в район наступления.

*[Что известно о прорыве Каховской ГЭС - ТАСС, 06.06.2023](https://tass.ru/proisshestviya/17936539)*

> [Dmitry] Peskov [Press Secretary of the President of Russia] said that the diversion at the Kakhovka hydroelectric power plant was carried out by Ukraine. According to him, it [the divsersion] was connected to the unsuccessful counteroffensive by Kyiv. [...]
> Minister of Defense of RF Sergei Shoigu said that the goal of Kyiv's blowing up of the Kakhovka hydroelectric power plant consists of relocation of Ukrainian Army units from the Kherson direction to the region of the attack.

*[What is known about the breach of the Kakhovka hydroelectric power plant - TASS, 06.06.2023](https://tass.ru/proisshestviya/17936539)*

Comment: It is interesting that the exact mirror arguments about moving troops away from the Kherson region has been used by Ukrainian-friendly voices: By making the territory harder to pass, Russia gains the opportunity to move forces to the Donbass.

Comment: Far from "exact mirror"! **Russia** is led by a known war criminal, **Russia** has been destroying Ukrainian infrastructure, **Russian** missiles terrorize civilians. The Kakhovka destruction is much more consistent with Russian than Ukrainian, actions so far. See: [UN: Half of Ukraine's Energy Infrastructure Destroyed by Russia](https://www.voanews.com/a/un-half-of-ukraine-energy-infrastructure-destroyed-by-russian-attacks/6874897.html), [Russian strikes against Ukrainian infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022%E2%80%932023_Russian_strikes_against_Ukrainian_infrastructure), etc.

Comment: @TimurShtatland If your comment was triggered by my use of the plural for "arguments", I apologise. This is merely a typo, I wanted just to point out the similarity in that single argument, without any judgment about its merrit when voiced by one side or the other, or generally saying which side has the better arguments. Like you said, leave it as an exercise to the readers.

Comment: @TimurShtatland, what's going on is a straightforward war - there's nothing exceptional about killings or destruction. I don't think anyone is discounting that Russia may have blown the dam, but so long as the two sides don't agree on what is true, it will be impossible to tell which one is lying. Neither side sustains a fatal blow, and rationales can be found for either having executed the act, so we will probably not know until much later, if ever.

Comment: @Steve discount or not, there is no chance that Russia didn't blow up the dam.  This answer addresses whether Ukraine may have gained any military benefit from it, but it is still unquestionably Russia that did it.

Comment: @Steve We might find some evidence in the near future. It's not rocket science, it's MI...

Comment: @wrod, there is in fact every chance. As with Nordstream, the desire may be to deprive Russia of the control over timing, and deprive them of the one-sided advantage granted by their possession of the dam. Russia may even have laid the explosives for its own deterrence purposes, yet saboteurs may have entered and triggered them. If thousands are swept away and drowned to gain advantage for the Western side, the US will just ask what's the difference between that and Ukrainian soldiers being killed on battlefields for the same advantage.

Comment: @Steve re: "there is in fact every chance." None.

Comment: @wrod, is the logic I expressed unsound in some way?

Comment: @Steve yes.  It lists known facts as "maybe"s and far-fetched highly-dubious scenarios, for which there is no evidence, as "possibly"s.  That's not called "logic".

Comment: @wrod, there's nothing far-fetched about any event, if it is physically feasible and it furthers the interests of a combatant. I tried to put meat on the scenarios, but the essential point is that neither side is unequivocally damaged by the event, and there are rationales by which they each gain advantage, so we cannot infer who is responsible, and we will not know unless they both agree on the fact. (1/2)

Comment: One thing nevertheless obvious is that there was no immediate reason why the dam was blown (in terms of Ukrainian forces amassing or threatening to cross) or why Russia would have done it pre-emptively when it could simply have maintained the threat, and it's the second such blowing of major infrastructure which Russia at first appeared intent on using for leverage and which it had enough control over (at the time of the blowing) to make triggering destruction at that moment seem unnecessary. (2/2)

Answer (score 9):

I haven't seen official explanations, but here is an explanation by Igor Strelkov, a prominent  Russian military blogger and former minister of defense in the Donetsk People's Republic (my translation):

> On the situation with the blowing up of the Kakhovskaya hydroelectric
> power station.  So far, briefly (information from the field has not
> yet reached, as of yesterday - everything was very calm, no one
> expected anything).
>
> 1. The blowing up clearly was pre-planned, purposeful and has an important place in the enemy's offensive plans.
> 2. So far, the following main goals seem to be:
>
> - "wash away" our troops from the left bank of the Dnieper below Novaya Kakhovka. That includes all defensive structures, all
>   minefields will be "washed away", all field ammunition depots will be
>   flooded, all property which the army won't have time to evacuate will
>   be completely or partially destroyed (and there will be a lot of this,
>   unfortunately);
> - to create conditions for capturing of the Kinburn Spit (which will also be partially flooded and turned into an island by flooding).  If
>   the enemy succeeds in capturing the Kinburn Spit now, he will unblock
>   the Ochakov port and the mouth of the Dnieper.  It will be extremely
>   difficult to recapture the spit (in the current conditions, it will be
>   nearly impossible);
> - create a threat (in a week or two) of crossing the Dnieper in a wide area above Novaya Kakhovka - after a very significant decrease in
>   the level of the reservoir and the same narrowing of the current water
>   barrier.  Whether they plan to cross or not is unpredictable, but the
>   command of Russian Armed Forces will have to transfer additional
>   Ukranian army to this sector for sure (otherwise they will definitely
>   cross and create a bridgehead).

[Original text in Russian](https://t.me/strelkovii/5281)

Strelkov also claims in the following posts, that apart from this, another advantage for Ukraine will be that the Russian Federation will now be burdened with disaster relief possibly affecting 30-50 thousand embittered refugees who may have partially or wholly lost their property as a result of the flooding. For the 10-20 thousand that will be affected on the Ukranian side, it also provides ammunition to the Ukranian for further propaganda that "*the evil Muscovites blew up the hydroelectric dam.*"

Comment: "A prominent military blogger" seems to be leaving a salient part of this esteemed person's CV:  [convicted of blowing up MH17 flight, killing 298, at the Hague](https://www.euronews.com/my-europe/2022/11/17/three-men-given-life-sentences-for-shooting-down-flight-mh17-over-ukraine-in-2014) .  Still, +1 for actually listing possible and somewhat credible reasons.  Outweighed by the much larger disadvantages to Ukraine, sure, but still...

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Credible? Wrecking havoc to roads and bridges you would need yourselves to advance, or to move through the mud at the bottom of a former sea bed do not look too compelling to me.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica that's literal translation of the quote. I am not sure why this should be taken out. I mean, it mentiones the theory that doesn't Kiev doesn't care about Russian minorities (important theory in this context) and also gives a clue what kind of the person Strelkov is.

Comment: @ccprog about the only one that makes any sense is a smaller Dnipro, but it would be quite a game-changer if it was geographically possible in a timely manner, which I kinda doubt.  For the rest, it is not a great list, but it is a list, which is what you asked for, and if anything it rather shows a rather poor match - Russia's gains are much more immediate and obvious.

Comment: @Kandi, oh right, I thought it was just the bullet points.  Still, since you find it important show what kinda person Strelkov is, I've already done the research for you ;-)

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I just looked at the article you linked, and I can't find the name Strelkow among the convicted. Care to comment?

Comment: @ccprog  good catch, I was sloppy in picking up the first clear article.  our good buddy has aliases.  Girkin == Strelkov :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igor_Girkin  https://interfax.com/newsroom/top-stories/85062/  Well, actually articles all use his real name for the Hague judgment, not Strelkov.

Comment: This thing being at high risk of deletion (2 votes so far), I've taken the liberty removing the *quote* about the refugees, Nazis, etc, which is **not** a military consideration so shouldn't be missed all that much.  I believe the rest is solidly relevant to the question as asked, which is to list what Russians might see as benefits.  Strelkov/Girkin might be an a**hole of epic proportion, but he's far from the worst-informed Russian war supporter.  Quoting what he has to say isn't unreasonable.

Answer (score 3):

The territory controlled by Russia is more affected by the destruction up the Kakhovka dam. [Even the Deputy Minister of Defense of Ukraine Anna Malyar confirms that](https://www.5.ua/ru/obshchestvo/podriv-kakhovskoi-hes-pryvel-k-zatoplenyiu-pozytsyi-rossyiskykh-voennikh-mynoboroni-307046.html):

> **The explosion of the Kakhovskaya HPP led to the flooding of the positions of the  Russian military – the Ministry of Defense**
>
> Deputy Minister of Defense of Ukraine Anna Malyar reported that the explosion of the Kakhovskaya HPP caused the flooding of the positions of Russian military units. This is reported by Ukrinform.
>
> "The positions of Russian military units were flooded, which could lead to a large–scale washing away of Russian minefields and their detonation in a chaotic manner," Malyar wrote.

*(She mentioned this while explicitly blaming Russia for blowing up the Kakhovka dam).*

Russian media outlet Pravda also outlines some reasons in favour of Kiev being behind the act, in its article [Destruction of the Kakhovskaya HPP dam: versions, causes, consequences](https://military.pravda.ru/1842751-kahovskaya_station/):

> The reasons for Kiev may be as follows:
>
> - Create a media channel for further sanctions against the Russian Federation and NATO's assistance to the Armed Forces. The visit of the British Foreign Minister James Cleverley to Ukraine, which ended yesterday, falls into this context ... the adviser to the head of the office of the president, Daria Zarivna, noted that "*the undermining of the Kakhovskaya HPP is fraught with a sharp desalination of the Black Sea.*" The head of the European Council, Charles Michel, stressed that he was shocked by the attack on the Kakhovskaya HPP, blamed Russia for it and called the incident a "war crime".
> - Stop the Russian counterattack in the Kherson region;
> - Flood the Russian defenses and advance themselves when the Dnieper becomes shallow — upstream.
> - Deprive Crimea of water in summer;
> - shift the focus from the failed counteroffensive of the Ukrainian Armed Forces on June 4-5.
>
> It is doubtful that the Russian army decided to drown itself and at the same time leave the NPP and Crimea without water. Again, the river level downstream should recover soon, so if this interferes with the APU offensive, it will be temporary.

Also one of the versions for the collapse of the spans of the Kakhovskaya HPP blames Ukraine *indirectly*. This version claims that it collapsed itself, as it was previously half-destroyed by the bombing of the APU, when the Armed Forces of the Russian Federation were in Kherson. The spans simply could not stand it — the resistance of the materials reached the limit .

Comment: I suggest that instead of posting new answers, you add this content to your previous answer that was deleted. And then appeal against the delete by clicking the "Undelete" link. Your previous answer was deleted unfairly, but posting new answers will be seen as trying to bypass moderation. Rather, trust the community and allow the reviewers to consider your content on its merit. (While it can be frustrating to see your research and effort in posting an answer here not be appreciated, and downvoted or deleted, don't view this as a confrontation but a discussion. Be patient with the community).

Comment: I'm failing to see the reason why someone would so desperately try posting the same content over and over. (1) [two](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/79855/) of your [posts](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/79865/) have been already **deleted by the community**, and this "answer" speaks essentially same arguments: slowing the UA counteroffensive, undermining RU positions on the left bank, prior UA destruction of RU-controlled bridges, depriving water to Crimea, accusations of RU committing war crimes […]

Comment: […] (2) The supporting links are different, but it not a tremendously hard task to find different links in a country where all media are controlled and must talk the same. (3) as of now, other answers above have reached relatively high scores as they *address the same points*, however do so in a much more neutral manner. (4) Your recent actions are being discussed [here on Meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6565/), please join if you wish.

Comment: @Be Brave Be Like Ukraine This is not the same content as in previous question, this time I have not reused anything from the previous answer. Also I have used an Ukrainian sorce this time, so you can´t just call it Russian propaganda. I defenetly should be more patient next time, this is something I am going to apologize for.

Comment: Where does it say it affects Russia more than Ukraine? You say that in your first sentence but the quote doesn't make that comparison at all. If anything the floating of mines seems a problem for Ukraine mostly because they're all floating on Ukrainian land, it's not like the mines will flow to Russia all of a sudden. That is, if the Russian troops retreat from the flooded area it will be the Ukrainians who are stuck with the mines

Comment: I don't think Russia planned to force the river but neither do I think that Ukraine planned to.

Comment: @JJJ My answer was edited.

Answer (score -4):

The Washington Post, [in an article on December 29, 2022](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2022/12/29/ukraine-offensive-kharkiv-kherson-donetsk/) describes how the Ukranian had considered, practised and simulated blowing up the dam in 2022:

> *“There were moments when we turned off their supply lines completely, and they still managed to build crossings,”* Kovalchuk said. *“They managed to replenish ammunition. … It was very difficult.”*
>
> Kovalchuk considered flooding the river. The Ukrainians, he said, even conducted a test strike with a HIMARS launcher on one of the floodgates at the Nova Kakhovka dam, making three holes in the metal to see if the Dnieper’s water could be raised enough to stymie Russian crossings but not flood nearby villages. The test was a success, Kovalchuk said ...

The left bank of the Dnieper, which is controlled by Russia, is lower than the right bank controlled by Ukraine. So Russia is getting more damage by the flood of water. This flooding will damage and deactivate many of the minefields laid out by Russia and could help Ukrainian troops to more easily cross unencumbered to the Russian side (via boats etc.).

As can be seen on Russian maps showing the river and its surrounding areas before the dam was destroyed:

[image: The river before the Kakhovka dam was blown up]

and the flooding that occurred after the dam was destroyed:

[image: Flooding after the Kakhovka dam was blown up]

- the side controlled by Russia is more affected.

Military experts quoted in an article - [Why did Kiev decide to flood: What is happening at the Kakhovskaya HPP](https://life.ru/p/1584690) (Russian) - describe how this further helps the Ukranian:

> **Why did the Armed Forces of Ukraine blow up the Kakhovskaya hydroelectric power station**

> The Dnieper spill complicates the AFU's plans for a counteroffensive in the southern direction. But it improves the situation in the direction above the Dnieper ... The May rains greatly increased the level of the reservoir above the dam.
>
> The undermining of the Kakhovskaya hydroelectric power station is connected with the plans of Kyiv, and is part of the general operation of the counteroffensive of the Armed Forces of Ukraine. It was a man-made explosion, with predictable results in the key - how much water will flow, how long the river will overflow. This affected the positions of the Russian army on the left bank. Because most of the settlements that were located on this side of the Dnieper, the same Bare Pier and a number of others, were equipped with Russian fortified areas, from which attacks were carried out on the AFU, military experts say.
>
> ***"Now they are flooded, we can't use mortar artillery and we can use barrel artillery to a very limited extent. The enemy gets the opportunity to concentrate artillery complexes and multiple launch rocket systems on the right bank and work according to the scheme of stray artillery, shelling our settlements further than usual,"*** military expert Alexey Leonkov comments on the situation.
>
> According to him, the lowered water level to the Kakhovka reservoir will make it possible to build pontoon crossings for the transfer of troops ... According to our experts, the explosion will ... eventually affect the North Crimean Canal.

*(Translated from Russian source using Google and Yandex translate)*.

Comment: +1 Would those downvoting care to explain why they are downvoting? The question asked why Ukraine would blow up the dam and this is one possible answer.

Comment: @CDJB This Question has already 2 delete flags so I have expected it to be deleted soon aniway.

Comment: @convert if the answer is deleted by the community and you disagree with the deletion, then please create a post on [our meta site](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/) explaining your argument rather than just reposting the deleted answer.

Comment: @convert community voting, like delete- and down-votes that your post has reaped a rich harvest of, exists for a purpose. Posting a duplicate **for a single purpose of evading the community vote**, as one of the forms of [sockpuppetry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388984/), should be considered a severe violation of the very founding principles of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Not the down voter, but can probably explain some of it: (1) this was originally an unsourced claim that Ukrainians can now just swim/boat across minefields - which is both ridiculous and suggests an unsupported amphibious assault would somehow be easier than a ground assault; (2) the quotes don't seem intellectually honest, and (3) the claims from the author don't seem well supported by the current quotes.

Comment: @sfxedit A downvoter, not VTD, and what bharring said in (1).  Most of my initial objections are gone by now.  IMHO, this Q doesn't really need said military arguments to be 100% right and uncounterable, only *to be reasonably relevant, in a military sense* (ruckpack-carrying, mine-swimming grunts were not).  This iteration is much more solid and on-topic.  Stripped of the *political verbiage*, for example the entire Nikita Mendkovich quote, I'd be inclined to upvote instead.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I felt the misunderstanding was because English doesn't appear to be convert's first language. (I have since edited his post to improve it). Didn't realise that at first, he hadn't cited any sources - that explains a lot.

Comment: You can improve your answer by adding the before and after photos from this source: https://t.me/rusfleet/8579

Comment: @sfxedit Exactly, English is not a language I am good in, specially when it comes to writing.

Comment: @bharring Tried to write an answer before the question got closed which was then incomplete, defenetly not a good idea.

Comment: Upvoted now, with the political quote gone.  Another thing that *might* benefit UA:  post-liberation Kherson has frequently been shelled from across the river, esp in the beginning.  Have/will some of the shorter range RU guns been, hmmm, flushed out by the water rise on the east bank?  No idea, and RU public announcers may wish not to emphasize how much they shell the city, but possible.