# What are the recently declassified documents about the destruction of Kakhovka dam?

Tags: ukraine, reference-request, war-crime

On 06 June 2023, in its article about the destruction of Kakhovka HPP dam, NBC News [said](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/live-blog/khakovka-dam-live-updates-ukraine-russia-blew-up-kherson-rcna87855#rcrd13608) (highlight mine):

> However, two U.S. officials and one Western official earlier told NBC News that *the U.S. has intelligence* that is leaning toward Russia as the perpetrator of the attack. U.S. officials were working to *declassify some of the intelligence* and share it as early as Tuesday afternoon.

Are these intelligence documents yet available?

There are several questions on this site discussing the matter, and the declassified intelligence documents could instantly resolve controversies like this:

- [Are there military arguments why the Russia would blow up the Kakhovka dam?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/79860/2984)
- [Are there military arguments why the Ukraine would blow up the Kakhovka dam?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/79852/2984)

Comment: Do you have a second (or even third) news source "promising" this evidence, without reference to NBC News? As it stands, I would rate it as unconfirmed rumor while your question makes it seem a fact.

Comment: @o.m. I'm afraid I cannot provide with what you requested. It is NBC citing anonymous source. I cannot think of a third party to say. "we independently confirm that yes, an anonymous source has indeed promised the intel evidence to NBC". It is not an established fact yet. My question was to verify that assertion, hence [tag:reference-request]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not quite the full answer you expected, but 10 days later NYT ran a [long piece](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2023/06/16/world/europe/ukraine-kakhovka-dam-collapse.html) on that. In it, it's mentioned that

> But multiple lines of evidence reviewed by The New York Times, from original engineering plans to interviews with engineers who study dam failures, support a different explanation: that the collapse of the dam was no accident. The catastrophic failure of its underlying concrete foundation was very unlikely to occur on its own. [...]
>
> A senior American military official said that the United States had ruled out an external attack on the dam, like a missile, bomb or some other projectile, and now assesses that the explosion came from one or more charges set inside it, most likely by Russian operatives.

And there are like 5-7 academic (engineering) and [named] military experts that essentially agree with that, in the NYT piece, plus NYT's own arguments/investigation.

A couple of days later, AP ran a [similar story](https://apnews.com/article/ukraine-russia-war-kakhovka-dam-collapse-investigation-f5b76fe1ddbf98aa5ff7e4dfd3199c38). Although it doesn't quote any US officials, it quotes the ISW etc.

So, the US intel community probably doesn't feel too pressured to release anything detailed, given that [US] OSINT researchers agree with their conclusion, and can provide plenty of details/arguments themselves.